# Using validator.getConstraintsForClass on an annotation gives different result than using getConstraintsForProperty containing the annotation

Tags: java, validation, annotations, constraints, bean-validation

I have a number of Java Annotation classes.

The idea is that developers/consumers of my project will use these annotations on fields inside their POJOs in order to describe each field.

Example relationship between these annotations: `@CustomString` -> `@CustomPassword`

Why is it that when I try to get the constraints on `@CustomPassword` using `validator.getConstraintsForClass`, the `min` does not contain the value specified inside `CustomPassword` i.e `10`

I want to use:

```
@OverridesAttribute(constraint = CustomString.class, name = "min")
int min() default 10;
```

To override the value because I'd like developers to be able to create their own annotation classes that sit on top of `CustomPassword` and maybe provide their own overrides.

`@CustomString` sets `@Size` `min` and `max` constraints:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.OverridesAttribute;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Size
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface CustomString {

  @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Size.class, name = "min")
  int min() default 0;

  @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Size.class, name = "max")
  int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  String message() default "{org.example.annotation.base.string}";
}
```

`@CustomPassword` which contains a reference to `@CustomString`, and attempts to override the `min` from `@CustomString`:

```
import org.ecample.annotation.base.CustomString;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.OverridesAttribute;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@CustomString
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface CustomPassword {

  @OverridesAttribute(constraint = CustomString.class, name = "min")
  int min() default 10;

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  String message() default "{org.example.annotation.extended.password}";
}
```

Why is it that when I run:

```
Class<?> klass = CustomPassword.class;
Validator validator =
        Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
            .buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = validator.getConstraintsForClass(klass);
```

The `constraintDescriptors` inside `BeanDescriptor` still has a `min` of `0`, shouldn't it have been overridden by the `min` inside `CustomPassword` and be set to `10`?

```
((BeanDescriptorImpl)beanDescriptor).constraintDescriptors.iterator().next().annotationDescriptor

@c.c.c.m.t.a.b.CustomString(groups=[Ljava.lang.Class;@3d9f0a5, max=2147483647, message={org.example.annotation.base.string}, min=0, payload=[Ljava.lang.Class;@1953bc95)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum code base example via github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to look at the bean descriptor of a constraint annotation itself. The `Validator#getConstraintsForClass(..)` is intended to provide the metadata for the bean. If you'd try something like:

```java
public class ConstrainedBean {
    @CustomPassword
    public String password;
}
//...

BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = validator.getConstraintsForClass( ConstrainedBean.class );
```

This bean descriptor will contain a constrained property and you'd be able to get the expected `10` navigating through `constraintDescriptor#composingConstraints` first to get to `CustomString` and then to `Size`.

When you are passing the `CustomPassword.class` you are getting a metadata as if you are going to validate the instance of a `CustomPassword.class` and at that point validator considers `CustomString` as a class-level constraint and  none of `OverridesAttribute` from `CustomPassword` are considered since beans do not override any constraint attributes.